# How do I get a correct Running Threshold Power with Garmin

Tags: running, heart-rate

I normal run based on my heart rate or feeling.

With my new Watch(Garmin Forerunner 955) I got access to training based on power. But my Running Threshold Power seems wrong(to high) or at least barely related to my heart rate zones.

Is this normal and if not, how do I set my Running Threshold Power correctly?

For example:
15km, 1:40:00, steady pace
[image]